# preg_match URL only code disallowing all text

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, preg-match

I have a `preg_match` if statement that is only supposed to allow valid URLs, but instead it doesn't allow any text whatsoever.

I've tried inputting various different things such as:

```
http://www.google.com/
http://www.google.com
www.google.com
google.com
```

and just "Google" (which shouldn't work anyway), but none of them work.

**Here's the code:**

```
  if (empty($_POST["link"]))
    {$linkErr = "A URL is required.";}
  elseif (!preg_match("%^((https?://)|(www\.))?([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i", $link))
    {$linkErr = "Please enter a valid URL.";}
  else
    {$link = test_input($_POST["link"]);}
```

As long as there is text in the box, it outputs "Please enter a valid URL," regardless of what the text is.

Comment: Why aren't you using a built-in function for this purpose? http://php.net/filter_var

Comment: Fix this line `~^(https?://)?(www\.)?~i`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Amal Murali, using the built-in `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` function works: http://php.net/filter_var

**The new if statement would be:**

```
if (empty($_POST["link"]))
    {$linkErr = "A URL is required.";}
  elseif (filter_var($_POST["link"], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE)
    {$linkErr = "Please enter a valid URL.";}
  else
    {$link = test_input($_POST["link"]);}
```

Comment: A link to the manual is not much of an answer, you should at least add an example of how to use it.